# Android In-App Billing: Purchasing real items with test accounts without spending money?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've already tested my In App Billing code using the static response codes, but I'm taking the next step to test with my real app ids.

I've got the ids configured in Google Play. I've got my test accounts set up.

When I try to initiate a test purchase, I'm asked to provide Credit Card info... is it going to charge me money?

I expected the test account to use a fake CC just like the static skus did.

Answer (score 2):

You have to input a real CC when testing as you said. When I tested in my app I just went into my Developer Console and cancelled the order by hitting the "Cancel Entire Order" button. Doing so refunded the money to my card.

Answer (score 2):

To test in app purchases you should set up a separate google account because you are unable to purchase your own apps.

Using the test account you should buy the item you are testing using a real and valid credit card.

If you go into your developer console, you can refund/cancel any order at any time. If you refund within about 15-20 minutes of purchase then the charge will never appear on your card. If you refund later than this then it will appear as a charge and a separate refund.

You do not lose anything. You can always refund the whole amount.

Ignore the message "This in-app purchase cannot be refunded". This applies to the purchaser. The developer has discretion to refund any order at any time. I have refunded an order that was over a year old in the past.

Update: This can now be done
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html?rd=1#test-purchases

Comment: At what point is this considered a good thing, at least with iOS you can do a sandbox purchase and not have to deal with real money transactions.

Comment: Hope we can do testing like what we do in iOS. It doesn't make sense to use the real credit card for testing.

Comment: It can. I updated my answer last year. You must not have read to the end.

Answer (score 1):

A test purchase shouldn't charge your card. Even if it does, you can immediately cancel the order. You can make a real purchase and immediately cancel the order to get a full refund.

I have performed multiple test and real In-App Purchase transactions on my own applications and have never been erroneously charged or unable to fully refund myself.

Here's the process I successfully use to refund purchases:

1. Find the order in question on your Google Checkout account and open the details page.
2. Use the following option to refund.

[image: Refund]

A refunded order in your Google Checkout transaction list should look something like this:

[image: Refunded]

I have had to refund myself on a few occasions (like above) and have never had a problem. I apologize if you've lost your $0.99 on my account.

Comment: So, I just tested a purchase, I -was- charged the money, I -was not- allowed to cancel as a user I had to cancel as the developer and I -was not- refunded any money when canceling.

Comment: It was only 99 cents, so it's not a big deal, but I clearly can't do this 100 times while testing my app.

Comment: @KennyWyland I'm not sure what process you used to refund the order but perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I'm going to edit my post.

Comment: I went to the same page you have in your screenshot. "Refund some money..." was greyed out and next to it was "Cancel this order" which was active. It was already listed as fully charged and I verified that with my credit card (it was a full charge and not just verification).

Comment: When I purchased the In App Billing item to begin with (and checked it again just now) it explicitly says: "This in-app purchase cannot be refunded."